# Spring Boot Switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL and getting unique constraint violations

Tags: mysql, spring, postgresql, spring-data

I am in the process of switching databases for a Spring Boot project from MySQL to PostgreSQL. For the most part this hasn't been too painful, however I am finding that I am getting an exception I can't seem to sort out.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "r_i_UNIQUE"
Detail: Key (cola_id, colb_id)=(1234567, 12345) already exists.
```

The behaviour in MySQL when this occurred was to perform an update, which is what I need to occur in PostgreSQL as well.

Code wise, I search for an existing item by the `cola_id` and `colb_id`, the object is returned from my repository, is manipulated as required and then persisted using `repository.saveAndFlush(existingItem);`

It is on the `saveAndFlush` that I get the exception.

My assumption is that Spring is seeing this as a new object and trying to do an insert rather than an update, but I am not understanding why this would occur as it worked as expected using MySQL.

How does PostgreSQL handle updates using saveAndFlush, and how can I get an update to apply correctly?

Comment: *I am not understanding why this would occur*: and yet you have the code. We don't. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Note: inside a transaction, you don't need to save objects that you get from your repository. These are managed objects. Their state is **automatically** saved to the database.

Comment: @JBNizet - Point taken - yet providing a plethora of code in this instance I felt would be a distraction. I removed the save and flush out of my code and it is now persisting to the database correctly. Thanks for the nudge. Any ideas why MySQL would have worked fine with this?

Comment: No. But I've learnt never to rely on MySQL doing things correctly.